# which is the best and simple algorithm for calendar?

Tags: algorithm, calendar

I am planning to display an android calendar in my application. I want to select a date to use in my application. I need to know whether there is an *algorithm for a calendar*.

I must not use any open source application.

Comment: Do you ask for date/time calculation, or for GUI and layout algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating an arbitrary Gregorian calendar pretty much amounts to [determining the day of the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week) of the starting day and, for Februaries, determining [whether the year is a leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

The best and most famous date algorithm is Conway's Doomsday Rule, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_rule

Comment: It's been said the year(described as 'y' in the article) is a two-digit number.... In the example y=66 stands for the year 1966. How can I calculate 2066,2166,2266,etc?